# Help identifying brand

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage

[image]

Looking for help identifying this brand. I must decide if it’s worth driving 2 hours for it! Got first dibs but owner doesn’t know what it is; I know enough to see it’s worth something;)

Update: serial number is D92548. Badge is “Seiberling Road King”; manufactured by Cleveland Welding Company/Seiberling Rubber Company.

I am now trying to date it[image][image][image]

Comment: Its pretty old - one piece crank, at best it has one brake inside the rear wheel, so not the best thing to actually ride.    We don't do valuations - if you need a bike and this is the nearest thing, then its worth it to you.     It does look particularly solid, which means heavy, so hope you will ride on the flat not up hills!   When you can, add clearer photos of that brassy badge on the top of the downtube, and any other similar identifiers.

Comment: The saddle-less purple mixte beside it looks like an 80s design - mostly based on the rear brake caliper.   There's a lot of rust, but can't tell if that is just surface or worse.  You'll likely need new tyres and brake pads if they've been stored a long time.

Comment: I am headed to see it tomorrow. Would love to clean it up and bring it back to life. I have already made offer and they accepted. I will definitely get more photos.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, which bike?  There are two in the picture.

Comment: The black men’s bicycle.

Comment: Can't tell much from the picture.  It's a single speed with coaster brakes, and the narrow tires on a single-speed are weird, suggesting that it's fairly old -- probably pre-1970, and maybe going back to 1950 or earlier.  Likely the pedals have been replaced, and probably the seat as well.  Looks like an old-style kickstand.

Comment: Note that  Seiberling was the name of the founder of Goodyear Tire in Akron, and his family was greatly into machining, so very likely either he or one of his relatives founded the bike company.  I can't find, however, any evidence that the two companies were ever connected.

Comment: Looking at images online, I would guess that the badge was originally painted, but that the paint has been removed at some point.  This does introduce the slight possibility that the bike is a forgery -- ie, that the badge was installed at some later date.  But that seems unlikely.

Comment: https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/seiberling-road-king-help.33110/

Comment: It should be noted that it's probably going to be impossible (or at least incredibly expensive) to buy new tires for this bike, so it's more of a museum piece than a bike you can ride.

Comment: 26x1.375 tires fit it, put some on and some new tubes; That’s what it had on when purchased (an old Goodyear set). Rode it last night just fine!

Comment: OK, but note that it badly needs service.  The chain is badly rusted and, at the very least, needs lube.  The bearings likely need to be opened up and cleaned/lubed.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I am going to remove all rust and true the wheels. Basically just clean and lube after that plus replace grips and that is all. I won’t be painting it.

Comment: Take care truing the wheels -- likely the spoke nipples are frozen.

Comment: And to remove the rust use a chemical rust remover of some sort (I'm fond of "wood bleach" containing oxalic acid) rather than using a wire brush or some such.

Comment: Update #2. Turns out after researching further, this is a Colson featherweight, badged by Seiberling. All parts are original except bar/grip and possibly saddle.
Serial number is 2548 with D2 under it. I assumed it was all one number. D is month (April) and 2 Is 1942.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this article](https://thecabe.com/forum/threads/seiberling-road-king-help.33110/) about a slightly different bike:

> This bike was manufactured by Cleveland Welding (CWC) for distribution
> and sale by the Seiberling Rubber Company. It is essentially a
> standard issue CWC bike using the second series post-war CWC 3-Gill
> pattern frame and the serial number places the build date in 1947,
> probably near the middle of that year. While the basic bike is common,
> the Seiberling badging is one of the less common badges that were used
> on these bikes.

Note that there is actually a Facebook group for these bicycles: "Cleveland Welding Company bicycle owners".  One post I find on the group suggests that the serial number is from 1945.

Comment: Thank you for that information Daniel.